# I am suffering Divide by Zero Error in my query

Tags: sql

I am keep on getting Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 33
Divide by zero error encountered. error in my query.

My Query :

```
Round(Convert(Float,(X1.Reported_Days)) /Convert(Float,(X1.Total_Days))*100,0) "Percentage",
```

Total Days = 8 
Reported_Days = 0

Kindly help me out for this issue.

Comment: Are you sure Convert(Float,(X1.Total_Days)) is coming up as 8.00?

Comment: Don't tag products not involved. Put one dbms tag back, for the one you're using.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a case when

```
 case when Convert(Float,(X1.Total_Days)) = 0 
          then 0 -- or anything you want
          else Round(Convert(Float,(X1.Reported_Days)) /Convert(Float,(X1.Total_Days))*100,0) 
         end
    "Percentage",
```

Comment: Tried it but still am getting error. Attached screen shot : http://imgur.com/a/oENb7

Comment: @Kapil edited, you may try this one (convert firts to check the 0 value).

Comment: I getting output. But ends with same error. Why this is so?

Comment: You ain't got another division in your query ?

Comment: Yea. You are right. Problem is in my another division not in above one. Really sorry & thanks for your awesome support. I got the perfect output. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, if the answer if fine, you may accept it : http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235